# Black screen using dedicated graphics

Tags: nvidia, dual-boot, graphics, gpu

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I also have win 7. the thing is I can only boot into both when I change graphics settings in the BIOS menu and I have to make it integrated. If I have it on switchable, when I try and boot into ubuntu, it shows a purple blank screen for a little while then screen goes blank. If I change it to integrated, I can boot into ubuntu fine and everything works. I don't want to keep going to the BIOS menu and changing it for ubuntu, I wish to leave it on switchable so that I can boot into windows and ubuntu. Also there is no problem when I try to boot into windows when it is on integrated but I want to boot into windows and use my dedicated graphics not, the integrated one.

I have a acer aspire 5750G, the dedicated Graphics card on it is a NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M. How can I make it so that I leave it on switchable and I can boot into ubuntu.

thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 1):

When you get the black screen, try installing the Nvidia module.  Open a console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, Log in, then type

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

Comment: the black screen is like a turned of screen most of the times, like you can tell the laptop is still turned on but you can that the led lights for the screen are all turned of ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
rdblacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 xdriver=vesa
```

to the boot command line when you see GRUB.
After you login, install the Nvidia driver provided. Finally reboot to see whether it takes effect of not

Comment: im still new to ubuntu and linux so i understand i hold down shift to open grub and then it lists ubuntu 12.04, ubuntu 12.04 recovery and windows 7 i think, so what do i do then ? how do i enter that command ?

Comment: just press e and then edit it